# Вывод второй таблицы в ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Возникла проблема. Имею две таблицы в SQLite, в первой нормально выводятся и добавляются данные. Во второй же в ListView ничего не выводит.
Вот код DBHeleper, здесь интересует table2. Подскажите пожалуйста. В чем ошибка?

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contacts";
public static final String add_summ = "contacts";

public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String summ1 = "summ";
public static final String date1 = "date";
public static final String time1 = "time";
public static final String category1 = "category";
public static final String account1 = "account";
public static final String comment1 = "comment";

public static final String table2 = "cons";

public static final String KEY_ID2 = "_id2";
public static final String summ2 = "summ2";
public static final String date2 = "date2";
public static final String time2 = "time2";
public static final String category2 = "category2";
public static final String account2 = "account2";
public static final String comment2 = "comment2";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + add_summ + "(" + KEY_ID
            + " INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + summ1 + " INTEGER NOT NULL," + date1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            time1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            category1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            account1 + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + comment1 + " text" + ");");

    db.execSQL("create table " + table2 + "(" + KEY_ID2
            + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + summ2 + " INTEGER NOT NULL," + date2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            time2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            category2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            account2 + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + comment2 + " text" + ");");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + add_summ);
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + table2);
    onCreate(db);

}

public boolean insertData(String sum,String date,String time, String categ, String acc, String comm) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(summ1,sum);
    contentValues.put(date1,date);
    contentValues.put(time1,time);
    contentValues.put(category1,categ);
    contentValues.put(account1,acc);
    contentValues.put(comment1,comm);
    long result = db.insert(add_summ,null ,contentValues);
   /* if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;*/
   return true;
}

public boolean insertData2(String sum2,String date1,String time1, String categ2, String acc2, String comm2) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues input = new ContentValues();
    input.put(summ2,sum2);
    input.put(date2,date1);
    input.put(time2,time1);
    input.put(category2,categ2);
    input.put(account2,acc2);
    input.put(comment2,comm2);
    long result =  db.insert(table2,null ,input);
  if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}
```

Вот добавление данных в table2.  При нажатии на кнопку у меня выводится "Data Inserted"

```
public void onClick(View a) {

   boolean isInserted = dbHelper.insertData2(sum.getText().toString(),
            data.getText().toString(),
            time.getText().toString(),
            category.getText().toString(),
            acc.getText().toString(),
            comment.getText().toString());

    if(isInserted = true)
        Toast.makeText(consumption.this,"Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
    Toast.makeText(consumption.this," NOT Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

А вот сам вывод в ListView, в нем ничего не показывается и не выдает никаких ошибок

```
 private ListView userList;


    DBHelper mDBHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    Cursor userCursor;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter userAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_conslist);
        userList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        mDBHelper = new DBHelper(this);


        mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        userList.invalidateViews();
        //Список клиентов
        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> clients = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

//Список параметров конкретного клиента
        HashMap<String, Object> client;

//Отправляем запрос в БД
        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.table2, null);
        // Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM add_summ", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

//Пробегаем по всем клиентам
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            client = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            //Заполняем клиента
            client.put(DBHelper.summ2, cursor.getString(1));
            client.put(DBHelper.date2, cursor.getString(2));
            client.put(DBHelper.time2, cursor.getString(3));
            client.put(DBHelper.category2, cursor.getString(4));
            client.put(DBHelper.account2, cursor.getString(5));
            client.put(DBHelper.comment2, cursor.getString(6));
            //Закидываем клиента в список клиентов
            clients.add(client);

            //Переходим к следующему клиенту
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();

//Какие параметры клиента мы будем отображать в соответствующих
//элементах из разметки adapter_item.xml
        String[] from = {DBHelper.summ2, DBHelper.date2,DBHelper.time2,DBHelper.category2,DBHelper.account2,DBHelper.comment2};
        int[] to = {R.id.textView, R.id.textView2,R.id.textView3,R.id.textView4,R.id.textView5,R.id.textView6};

//Создаем адаптер
        final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, clients, R.layout.adapter_item2, from, to);


        userList.setAdapter(adapter);



    }
```

Comment: Не факт, что относится к делу, однако
`if(isInserted = true)`
может некорректно выполнять проверку (с java не работал давно, уже не помню, что она делает в таких случаях). Соответственно, возможен неверный вывод об успешной вставке.
Должно быть `if(isInserted == true)` по идее.
P.s. проверил, строка действительно ошибочна)